# What to do after becoming Sanyasi?

Tags: moksha, sanyasi

Suppose a person becomes Sanyasi (to get Moksha) .
What is he supposed to do afterwards ? What is the exact process of getting Moksha ?

Comment: You can formally become a sanyasi after getting proper initiation from a Guru, thereafter you follow the instructions of your guru

Answer (score 0):

`Suppose a person becomes Sanyasi (to get Moksha)`

*State of a Normal Jiva*

No being (jiva) can ever remain without action. (At the levels of Kayika, Vachika Manasika). Hence, inevitably engages with the world (/other beings) that suits ones own nature.

*Bhagavad Gita 3.5*

> There is no one who can remain without action even for a moment. Indeed, all beings are compelled to act by their qualities - of material nature (the three guṇas)

*Karma yog, Bhakti yog is the precursor (without which mere  sanyaas of karma is a futile effort)*

*Bhagavad Gita 5.6*

> Perfect renunciation (karm sanyās) is difficult to attain without performing work in devotion (karm yog), O mighty-armed Arjun, but the sage who is adept in karm yog quickly attains the Supreme
> .(Translation by Swami Mukundananda)

`what is he supposed to do afterwards?`

(*Strive to achieve BrahmaNishta*)

> People usually think that yoga means no more than controlling the breath
> and sitting stone-like. **The literal meaning of the word yoga is "joining", "uniting".** All through our life's journey we have to join ourselves to various objects. But such joining is no permanent. That is why the mind remains unsteady. If we are joined to an object without the least possibility of being separated from it, it is yoga in the true sense. The root of the minds of all of us is the one Paramatman. Yogins control their breath to turn their mind to this prime root object. The root that gives
> rise to thoughts is the same as the root that gives rise to the breath. So if the breath is fixed on the root, the mind too will be absorbed in it.
> *Hindu Dharma the Universal way of life, Pujyasri Chandrasekhara Saraswati Swami*

`What is the exact process of getting Moksha?`

**Brahma Sutra 3.4.52**

> Liberation is not an effect to be attained; it is only to be realized through knowledge, since it is eternally existent. (It is not some thing to be brought into existence by any action, since it is ever present and has only to be realized as such).
>
> *Sri Shankara Bhashya,BS 3.4.52 translated by Sri SN Sastri*

PS. Moksha can understood as an absolute freedom from all limitations imposed by acquiring jivahood, or by being in realm of Maya. Lord Krishna in BG says the possibility to achieve this  is to become Gunatheetha (transcend trigunas), also the Lord says "Mama Maya Durathyaya" (difficult to overcome the realm of Maya).

Though not impossible, it is highly improbable to achieve the state of a Gunatheetha to attain moksha. So there is another mukti known as Krama Mukti (eg contemplating a personal form of Brahman, resulting in attainment of respective lokas). This does not mean that Sri Shankaracharya is not in favour of Krama mukti, else His Loftiness, would not have consecrated deities (Murth) in many temples.

It is only in the light of Upanishads, the concept of moksha as ultimate liberation is explained in Bhasyas (commentaries).

> There is another kind of liberation known as kramamukti or liberation by stages. Those who meditate on Om go to Brahmaloka and attain liberation there 
> *Sri Shankara Bhashya, Brahma Sutra.4.3.15. translation Sri SN saastri*

> Kramamukti is achieved by the performance of one’s ordained duties coupled with contemplation on the Vedic deities of the jīva (the individual soul). It takes to the Arcīrādimārga and goes to Brahmaloka. Final liberation results from the dissolution of the Brahmaloka at the end of the cycle of the creation.
> Swami Harshananda